Android Studio Ladybug Flutter iOS Xcode build Error
Not able to figure out what can be done, as everything is update to date and the app via Xcode but not through Android Studio
MacOS 15.0.1
Flutter: 3.24.3
Android Studio Ladybug
Xcode 16
iOS 18 simulator
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/bd/31rc39_j2950dp6y2ycmj2w00000gn/T/flutter_tools.egRRKp/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirUyzp0X/temporary_xcresult_bundle

    /Volumes/Hitesh's Drive/Flutter projects/innerscope/ios/Pods/GTMAppAuth/GTMAppAuth/Sources/AuthSession.swift:297:22: warning: capture of 'request' with non-sendable type 'NSMutableURLRequest' in a
    `@Sendable` closure; this is an error in the Swift 6 language mode
                request: request,
                         ^
    Foundation.NSMutableURLRequest:2:12: note: class 'NSMutableURLRequest' does not conform to the 'Sendable' protocol
    open class NSMutableURLRequest : NSURLRequest {
               ^
    ld: warning: object file (/Volumes/Hitesh's Drive/Flutter projects/innerscope/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Pods_Runner.framework/Pods_Runner[3](Pods-Runner-dummy.o)) was built for newer 'iOS' version
    (16.0) than being linked (12.0)
    mkdir -p /Volumes/Hitesh's Drive/Flutter projects/innerscope/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Runner.app/Frameworks
    rsync --delete -av --filter P .*.?????? --links --filter "- CVS/" --filter "- .svn/" --filter "- .git/" --filter "- .hg/" --filter "- Headers" --filter "- PrivateHeaders" --filter "- Modules"
    "/Volumes/Hitesh's Drive/Flutter projects/innerscope/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/AppAuth/AppAuth.framework" "/Volumes/Hitesh's Drive/Flutter
    projects/innerscope/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Runner.app/Frameworks"
    building file list ... done
    AppAuth.framework/
    AppAuth.framework/AppAuth
    AppAuth.framework/Info.plist
    AppAuth.framework/AppAuthCore_Privacy.bundle/
    AppAuth.framework/AppAuthCore_Privacy.bundle/Info.plist
    AppAuth.framework/AppAuthCore_Privacy.bundle/PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy

    sent 311368 bytes  received 120 bytes  622976.00 bytes/sec
    total size is 310892  speedup is 1.00
    Code Signing /Volumes/Hitesh's Drive/Flutter projects/innerscope/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Runner.app/Frameworks/AppAuth.framework with Identity Apple Development: hiteshchaudhari1998@gmail.com
    (RJJ9F3WWH9)
    /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign 77636A61464C3680608DB30F7095FB02D0F5237F  --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements '/Volumes/Hitesh's Drive/Flutter
    projects/innerscope/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Runner.app/Frameworks/AppAuth.framework' &
    /Volumes/Hitesh's Drive/Flutter projects/innerscope/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner-frameworks.sh: eval: line 174: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Disabling previews because SWIFT_VERSION is set and SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL=-O, expected -Onone (in target 'shared_preferences_foundation' from project 'Pods')
    note: Disabling previews because SWIFT_VERSION is set and SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL=-O, expected -Onone (in target 'shared_preferences_foundation-shared_preferences_foundation_privacy' from project
    'Pods')
    note: Disabling previews because SWIFT_VERSION is set and SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL=-O, expected -Onone (in target 'google_sign_in_ios-google_sign_in_ios_privacy' from project 'Pods')
    note: Disabling previews because SWIFT_VERSION is set and SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL=-O, expected -Onone (in target 'google_sign_in_ios' from project 'Pods')
    note: Disabling previews because SWIFT_VERSION is set and SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL=-O, expected -Onone (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    note: Run script build phase 'Run Script' will be run during every build because the option to run the script phase "Based on dependency analysis" is unchecked. (in target 'Runner' from project
    'Runner')
    note: Run script build phase 'Thin Binary' will be run during every build because the option to run the script phase "Based on dependency analysis" is unchecked. (in target 'Runner' from project
    'Runner')
    note: Disabling previews because SWIFT_VERSION is set and SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL=-O, expected -Onone (in target 'Pods-Runner' from project 'Pods')
    /Volumes/Hitesh's Drive/Flutter projects/innerscope/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.0, but the range of supported deployment
    target versions is 12.0 to 18.0.99. (in target 'GoogleSignIn-GoogleSignIn' from project 'Pods')
    note: Disabling previews because SWIFT_VERSION is set and SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL=-O, expected -Onone (in target 'GoogleSignIn-GoogleSignIn' from project 'Pods')
    /Volumes/Hitesh's Drive/Flutter projects/innerscope/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.0, but the range of supported deployment
    target versions is 12.0 to 18.0.99. (in target 'GoogleSignIn' from project 'Pods')
    note: Disabling previews because SWIFT_VERSION is set and SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL=-O, expected -Onone (in target 'GoogleSignIn' from project 'Pods')
    /Volumes/Hitesh's Drive/Flutter projects/innerscope/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.0, but the range of supported deployment
    target versions is 12.0 to 18.0.99. (in target 'GTMSessionFetcher-GTMSessionFetcher_Full_Privacy' from project 'Pods')
    note: Disabling previews because SWIFT_VERSION is set and SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL=-O, expected -Onone (in target 'GTMSessionFetcher-GTMSessionFetcher_Full_Privacy' from project 'Pods')
    /Volumes/Hitesh's Drive/Flutter projects/innerscope/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.0, but the range of supported deployment
    target versions is 12.0 to 18.0.99. (in target 'GTMSessionFetcher-GTMSessionFetcher_Core_Privacy' from project 'Pods')
    note: Disabling previews because SWIFT_VERSION is set and SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL=-O, expected -Onone (in target 'GTMSessionFetcher-GTMSessionFetcher_Core_Privacy' from project 'Pods')
    /Volumes/Hitesh's Drive/Flutter projects/innerscope/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.0, but the range of supported deployment
    target versions is 12.0 to 18.0.99. (in target 'GTMSessionFetcher' from project 'Pods')
    note: Disabling previews because SWIFT_VERSION is set and SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL=-O, expected -Onone (in target 'GTMSessionFetcher' from project 'Pods')
    /Volumes/Hitesh's Drive/Flutter projects/innerscope/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.0, but the range of supported deployment
    target versions is 12.0 to 18.0.99. (in target 'GTMAppAuth-GTMAppAuth_Privacy' from project 'Pods')
    note: Disabling previews because SWIFT_VERSION is set and SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL=-O, expected -Onone (in target 'GTMAppAuth-GTMAppAuth_Privacy' from project 'Pods')
    /Volumes/Hitesh's Drive/Flutter projects/innerscope/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.0, but the range of supported deployment
    target versions is 12.0 to 18.0.99. (in target 'GTMAppAuth' from project 'Pods')
    note: Disabling previews because SWIFT_VERSION is set and SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL=-O, expected -Onone (in target 'GTMAppAuth' from project 'Pods')
    /Volumes/Hitesh's Drive/Flutter projects/innerscope/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment
    target versions is 12.0 to 18.0.99. (in target 'AppAuth-AppAuthCore_Privacy' from project 'Pods')
    note: Disabling previews because SWIFT_VERSION is set and SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL=-O, expected -Onone (in target 'AppAuth-AppAuthCore_Privacy' from project 'Pods')
    /Volumes/Hitesh's Drive/Flutter projects/innerscope/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment
    target versions is 12.0 to 18.0.99. (in target 'AppAuth' from project 'Pods')
    note: Disabling previews because SWIFT_VERSION is set and SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL=-O, expected -Onone (in target 'AppAuth' from project 'Pods')
    note: Disabling previews because SWIFT_VERSION is set and SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL=-O, expected -Onone (in target 'Flutter' from project 'Pods')


Tried Flutter downgrading but didn't work. Tried "flutter clean", "pod deintegrate", deleted Pods and Podfile.lock and installed pods again. Got same results.

Found the solution, the real issue was regarding a single quote (') that was present in the project path, that let to this issue.
Removed the single quote from the drive name and now it is resolved.

For android studio to run iOS Platform, you should try run app by command line using Terminal.
Then switch back to Android studio. And now you can run.
Remember to set platform target larger than 13

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
